# Generate 10,000 unique 9-digit numbers

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        long number = (long) Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000000) + 100000000L;
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't generate 10,000 random numbers. Why?

Comment: do you want unique or random? random may be repeated..

Comment: You mean, it generates 10,000 random numbers, but they repeat? Or what is the problem?

Comment: Random doesn't mean unique: see Birthday paradox http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem in your case you can expect about 2*sqrt(90000000) = 2e4 unique numbers

Comment: A good example of Random Numbers in a range .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-numbers-in-a-range-with-java

Comment: Btw: do we need "long" for 9 digits?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this is not a code review or debugging service.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't require uniform distribution, you could start with 100,000,000 and add an increment randomly chosen between [1 and 89,999]. Repeat 10,000 times.

This will give you a non-repeating sequence of numbers that are somewhat randomly generated.

But they will not be uniformly distributed (it is very unlikely to get numbers in the high ranges, like 999,xxx,xxx), and they will be strictly ascending, so you have a good chance to guess the next one if you know the previous one ("good" = 1/89999).

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer> uniques = new HashSet<>(15000);
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000;) {
        int number = random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        if (uniques.add(number)) {
            System.out.println(i + ": " + number);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe pre-size the HashSet. It's going to get big.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Set`, you can ensure uniqueness. Try,

```
 Set<Long> resSet=new HashSet<>();
 for(int i = 0;  resSet.size()<10000; i++){
     long number = (long) Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000000) + 100000000L;
     resSet.add(number);
 }
 System.out.println(resSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I did the following, generate random number and check it has been generated before, if not, just use and note it.

```
List<String> gen = new ArrayList<String>();
long number=0;
int i=0;

while(i<10000)
{
   while(!gen.contains(number) || i==0)
      number = (long) Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000000) + 100000000L;
   gen.add(number);
   System.out.println(number);
   i++;
}
```

I didn't tested the code since I did it in .NET, but I searched for code equivalencies.

Hope it helps!

Comment: i did try this and i got 10,000 random numbers,but these numbers are of 8 and 9-digit values(characters).....i want only 9 digit values

Comment: I used your algorithm to get number... so try this instead... replace: number = (long) (Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999999D) + 100000000L);
Adding 100000000 to random should return a 9-digit value.

Answer (score 0):

A minor contribution to @Masud's code:

```
         Set<Long> resSet = new HashSet<Long>();
         while(true) {
             long number = (long) Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000000) + 100000000L;
             resSet.add(number);
             if(resSet.size() == 10000)
                 break;
         }
```

This way you can surely get 10000 unique numbers (since the `for` loop does not guarantee that).

One drawback of this approach is that it "perishes" several numbers (which are the same as previous ones). I don't know if there is some more clever approach to this.